# How to calculate relationship between two members in an Ancestry public tree

Tags: ancestry.com, relationship-analysis

If I'm looking at someone else's Ancestry public family tree, how do I calculate the relationship between two people in their tree? Even just to be able to calculate the relationship to the home person in their tree would be good.

Ancestry support topics only suggest how to calculate the relationship in your own tree but not third-parties.

Answer (score 1):

There's no automatic way to make that connection via the tools on Ancestry.  Probably the best you can do within Ancestry is to examine the pedigrees for each person in that tree ("Tree Search", "home person" or *name*, Tools - "view in tree", then click the pedigree icon), and check each pedigree for common ancestors.

Answer (score 0):

Use Geni: Use the ["SmartCopy" browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smartcopy/ofikakkdpjlipbnhbfloclbkcabdhjah?hl=en) to copy to Geni world family tree whatever relevant data is on Ancestry and not in Geni. Once done, ask Geni to calculate the relationship.